# Regex help to get value from the outer most brackets

Tags: java, javascript, regex

Can you help me to get the values from the outermost braces, the search string can vary?

```
  String search = "hostProductLineCode:eq(YB) || hostProductLineCode:eq(PB) || (readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00))";
```

Want get the below values from above
   YB
      PB
      readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)

```
      search = "(readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)) || (liveDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00))";
```

Want get the below values from above
   readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)
      liveDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)

```
       search = "hostProductLineCode:eq(YB);hostProductLineCode:eq(PB);(readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)||StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00))";
```

Want get the below values from above
   YB
      PB
         readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)||StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)

```
 search = "hostProductLineCode:eq(YB);hostProductLineCode:eq:eq(V);(readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)||StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00));(status:eq(V)||status:eq(P))";
```

Want get the below values from above

```
   YB
      V 
     readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)||StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00));(status:eq(V)||status:eq(P)
```

I have tried below

```
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(search);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
              }
```

Comment: Please see my code that i have tried.

Comment: it looks to me like your code is getting the value from the outermost braces. Can you post the expected output?

Comment: If the "outpermost pair of parentheses" is always within a section separated by `||` you can split by that and then apply a regular expression to each section, but with a "greedy" quantifier `"\\((.*)\\)"`.

Comment: You should also update what u want get from every example you gave.

Comment: Updated what i want to get from above.

Comment: does it have to be a regex ?

Comment: It can be other way also, but prefer regex.

Comment: did any of the answers solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Split the String based on `||` and then use  `\(.*\)` regex to match. `.*` is greedy quantifier. It tries to get the largest possible match.

Comment: || can be different value, i can not use this logic, is there logic to get just values from the outermost not dependent on ||.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code.
Note: it's C#, but you can easily convert to Java or JS if you want. It's commented so you can easily follow the logic.

It basically scans your strings and copies all the stuff in between external brackets:

```
void Main()
{
    String search = @"hostProductLineCode:eq(YB) || 
                        hostProductLineCode:eq(PB) || 
                        (readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00))";
    GetParenthesis(search).Dump();   

    search = @"(readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)) 
        || (liveDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00))";
    GetParenthesis(search).Dump();      

}

// Define other methods and classes here
private IEnumerable<string> GetParenthesis(string aSource) {
    int status = 0; // you'll copy chars when this is 1 or bigger

    List<string> list_of_string = new List<string>();   // Hold the strings 
    StringBuilder temp_string = new StringBuilder();    // Hold temp string we're copying

    for (int i = 0; i < aSource.Length; i++)
    {
        // Deal with open bracket
        if (aSource[i].Equals('(')) {
            if (status ==0)
                i++; // to skip the first "("
            status++;
        }
        // Deal with close bracket
        else if (aSource[i].Equals(')')) {
            status--;
            if (status==0) { // need to add to list
                list_of_string.Add(temp_string.ToString());
                temp_string.Clear();    // reset temp string
            }
        }

        // Copy if in between brackets
        if (status>=1)
            temp_string.Append(aSource[i]);
    }

    return list_of_string;
}
```

Running the main section (I'm using linqpad), will return:

```
List<String> (3 items)
YB 
PB 
readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00) 

List<String> (2 items) 
readyDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00) 
liveDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00);StartDate:ge(2014-01-13T05:00:00)
```

which seems like what you want.